# When the series of orthogonal functions converges absolutely?

Tags: convergence-divergence, orthogonality, absolute-convergence

It is given a family of functions $\phi_n(t)$ orthogonal in $[0, T]$, $0 < T < \infty$. What conditions must $\phi_n$ satisfy in order to have
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |\phi_n(t)| \leq c < \infty?
$$

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: is it just a curiosity or did you step into this problem somewhere? If it is the second, can you add a little context?

Comment: It arises in controllability analysis of nonlinear systems. At one of intermediate steps it is required to provide that
$$
\left| \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_a^b K(x, \xi) \phi_n(\xi) dx d\xi \right| \leq c_0 < \infty.
$$
where $K$ is a given kernel. Thus, if the series of $\phi_n$ is absolutely convergent, then this is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, but you need less than absolute convergence and answering this last problem is simpler :)

Comment: Thus, if the series of $\phi_n$ is absolutely convergent, say,
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |\phi_n(x)| \leq c_1,
$$
then we deduce a restriction on $K$:
$$
\int_a^b |K(x, \xi)| dx d\xi \leq \frac{c_0}{c_1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If your family of functions belongs to a [RKHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) $\mathcal{H}$ of functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb{C}$ with the scalar product defined as:
$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_0^Tf(t)\overline{g(t)}\operatorname{dt}$$
then the pointwise absolute convergence is easily achieved, because point evaluations are continuous.

Under the hypothesis that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\|\varphi_n\|_2^2<+\infty$$
we have (by orthogonality) that $(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\varphi_n)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, and so (by completeness) it converges in norm to a (unique) $\varphi\in\mathcal{H}$. So, if $k_t\in\mathcal{H}$ is the element in $\mathcal{H}$ that represents the point evaluation in $t$ via the scalar product of $\mathcal{H}$  (it exists and it is unique thanks to Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces) then:

$$\varphi(t)=\langle\varphi,k_t\rangle=\langle \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\varphi_n,k_t\rangle = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\langle \sum_{n=1}^N\varphi_n,k_t\rangle \\ = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\langle \varphi_n,k_t\rangle = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\varphi_n(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi_n(t).$$

On the other hand, we get the same conclusion if $n :\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is any bijection because, thanks to orthogonality, the series $(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\varphi_n)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unconditionally convergent to $\varphi$ and so with the very same proof we get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\varphi_{n_k}(t)=\varphi(t).$$
So the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi_{n}(t)$$ is unconditionally convergent to $\varphi(t)\in\mathbb{C}$.
But a series of complex numbers converges if and only if its real and imaginary part converge, so we get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi_{n}(t)$$
has real and imaginary part unconditionally convergent.
Then, thanks to [Riemann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) we get that both real and imaginary part of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\varphi_{n}(t)$$ are absolutely convergent and then, from:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|\varphi_{n}(t)|\le \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|\operatorname{Re}(\varphi_{n}(t))| + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|\operatorname{Im}(\varphi_{n}(t))| < +\infty,$$
we get the conclusion.

Comment: So, if $\phi_n$ are RKHS, then their series is absolutely convergent?

Comment: A sequence is not a RKHS. They have to belongs to a RKHS and the series of their squared norm has to be finite

Comment: ok, I see. Do you have any examples of such orthogonal functions in mind?

Comment: Unfortunately not... the closed non-trivial RKHS space that I know and maybe could fit your problem is a Paley-Wiener space, but for such a space the functions $\varphi_n$ has to be defined on the whole $\mathbb {R}$ (not only on [0,T]) and they have to be orthogonal on the whole space...

Comment: I was thinking about applying the Weierstrass M-test using the orthogonality of $\phi_n$ somehow, but didn't succeed.

Comment: The problem is that you strongly need that pointwise evaluations are continuous functionals of the space where your functions live, otherwise also if the series of functions converges in norm, the pointwise series may very well diverges...